# bukkit plugin minecraft chests fill and build from class with int in list

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I have a List

```
private List<ChestPoint> chestpoints = new ArrayList<>();
```

and ChestPoint.java

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
String findhardness;
String arena;
```

and want to set chests and fill them with

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("buildfillchests")) {
    ItemStack itemsforchest = new ItemStack(Material.CHEST, 1728);
    if(args.length == 1){
        for(ChestPoint cp : chestpoints){
            Location chestloc = null;
            if(cp.arena == null ? args[0] == null : cp.arena.equals(args[0])){
                chestloc.setX(cp.x);
                chestloc.setY(cp.y);
                chestloc.setZ(cp.z);
                if(chestloc.getBlock().getType() == Material.AIR){
                    chestloc.getBlock().setType(Material.CHEST);
                    Inventory chestinv = ((Chest) chestloc.getBlock().getState()).getInventory();
                    chestinv.addItem(itemsforchest);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(args.length == 3 && "by".equals(args[0]) && "all".equals(args[1]) && "chests".equals(args[2])){
            for(ChestPoint cp : chestpoints){
                Location chestloc = null;
                chestloc.setX(cp.x);
                chestloc.setY(cp.y);
                chestloc.setZ(cp.z);
                if(chestloc.getBlock().getType() == Material.AIR){
                    chestloc.getBlock().setType(Material.CHEST);
                    Inventory chestinv = ((Chest) chestloc.getBlock().getState()).getInventory();
                    chestinv.addItem(itemsforchest);
                }
            }
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Es funktioniert nur /buildfillchests <arena> oder /buildfillchests by all chests");
    }
}
```

That does not work!
I want to build chests on all in the List chestpoints setted chestpoints and fill the chests with chests! But in my log file is no error logged! 
Can anybody find my mistace?

Comment: Did you register the command in your plugin.yml?

Comment: try setting `itemsforchest` to an ItemStack with only 64 items and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to call the BlockState.update() methods to apply the BlockState back to the actual Block.

http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/doxygen/d9/d1c/interfaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1block_1_1BlockState.html#a0734c83720823a6eb2247aaf4b60ec0e